# Alternating sequence without L'Hopital rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I tried to solve this limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \ \sqrt[n]{\frac{3^n+(-1)^n}{n^2}}$$ by observing that $(-1)^n$ can have two values depending if $n$ is even or odd.

For $n$ is even, I have:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \ \sqrt[2n]{\frac{3^{2n}+1^{2n}}{{4n}^2}}$$ than I tried extracting $3^n$ and got $$3\cdot\lim_{n\to \infty} \ \sqrt[2n]{\frac{1+(\frac{1}{3})^{2n}}{{4n}^2}}$$
After this, I did $$3 \cdot \ \lim_{n\to \infty} \exp\left[\ln{\frac{1+(\frac{1}{3})^{2n}}{{4n}^2}}\right]$$
and I don't know what to do next with this one. And for odd $n$ I also stop at this point.

Please help me using simple limit manipulation, it can be solved without using notations etc.

Comment: If you're taking evens, you should have $$\sqrt[2n]{\frac{3^{2n}+1}{(2n)^2}}$$

Comment: It was a typo, then what?

Comment: Also  $$3\cdot\sqrt[2n]{\frac{1+3^{-2n}}{(2n)^2}} \neq 3\cdot\exp\left[\ln\frac{1+3^{-2n}}{(2n)^2}\right] $$ I think you're missing a $\frac{1}{2n}$ outside the logarithm

Comment: Please edit my text if you can, I'm new here.

Comment: $\lim \frac {a_n} {b_n}=\frac {\lim a_n} {\lim b_n}$. This makes the answer quite simple.

Comment: You can't do that here. You are completely wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  **Squeeze** your expression between two simpler ones.

$$  \frac{3^n - 1}{n^2} \leq \frac{3^n + (-1)^n}{n^2} \leq  \frac{3^n + 1}{n^2}  \text{.}  $$

Comment: What happened with n-th root? Do I need it?

Comment: @dzaralica69 : The $n^\text{th}$ root function is monotonically increasing, so $a \leq b$ if and only if $\sqrt[n]{a} \leq \sqrt[n]{b}$.  (If those roots exist.  For instance $-1 \leq 1$, but $\sqrt{-1} \not \leq \sqrt{1}$ because (in the reals), that first square root does not exist.)

Comment: Thanksss very much!

Answer (score 1):

What you are left with in the end is $$\exp\left(\frac1{2n}\ln\left(\frac{1+\left(\frac13\right)^{2n}}{n^2}\right)\right)$$
You can decompose the logarithm in a difference, i.e.
$$ \frac1{2n}\ln\left(\frac{1+\left(\frac13\right)^{2n}}{n^2}\right)=\frac1{2n}\ln\left(1+\left(\frac13\right)^{2n}\right)-\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$
The first term trivially converges to zero, and it is known that the second also does.

So the whole exponential  converges to $1$ and the limit you are looking for is $3$.

Comment: I think It's $\ln{n^2}$ and not $\frac{\ln{n}}{n}$

Comment: $\ln(n^2)=2\ln(n)$ and the $2$ is simplified with the $\frac1{2n}$ in factor.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

we can let:
$$L(n)=\left(\frac{3^n+(-1)^n}{n^2}\right)^{1/n}$$
and because it is alternating we can say that:
$$\left(\frac{3^n-1}{n^2}\right)^{1/n}\le L(n)\le\left(\frac{3^n+1}{n^2}\right)^{1/n}$$

---

If we now focus on that upper limit:
$$L_2=\left(\frac{3^n+1}{n^2}\right)^{1/n}=\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\left[\ln(3^n+1)-2\ln(n)\right]\right)$$
now note that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(3^n+1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}3^n\tag{1}$$
and so we can say:
$$\ln(3^n+1)-2\ln(n)=n\ln(3)-2\ln(n)$$
we can simplify our limit to:
$$L_2=\exp\left(\frac{n\ln(3)-2\ln(n)}{n}\right)$$
$$\ln(L_2)=\ln(3)-\frac{2\ln(n)}{n}$$
which for $n\to\infty$ gives:
$$\ln(L_2)=\ln(3)$$
and so $L_2=3$

---

Now since our assumption of $(1)$ is also true for our lower limit, we can say:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}L(n)=3$$

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln{n}{n}$ equal to, and shortly why?

Comment: do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n}=0$?

Comment: No, I know that, but my limit is when n aproches 0 not infinity

Comment: In the question it says infinity

Comment: Oh yeah, mistaken.